# How are session variables effected by cookies?

Tags: php, session

EDIT (Answer):

If you change your sub-domain say from www.hotname.com to hostname.com you will change cookies.  If your session rely on cookies(mine do) then you will have a new set of session variables.

In short keep track of your domains/sub-domains when working with cookies.

Comment: Since you have a good rep, I am sure you are fully aware that this is *not* the place to report PHP bugs, it is a Q&A site. The Q in Q&A stands for "Question", and questions are things that normally have a `?` at the end of them. If you want to report a bug in PHP, [report it](https://bugs.php.net/). If you want people to help you find a problem in your test environment code or otherwise tell you why you see the effects you observe, please state this, preferably in the form of a question.

Comment: @DaveRandom: I think he's asking to make sure it really is a bug (which it isn't)

Comment: @SLaks fair enough (and I didn't mean to sound quite as sarky as that came out) but I do still maintain that this is not a very well phrased question (notably, the lack of an actual question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The session ID is stored in a cookie.

When you click `Login`, you generate a cookie for `archemarks.com`, then redirect to `www.archemarks.com`, which has no cookie.

Comment: @stack.user.0: Different domains don't share cookies.

Comment: First your using archemarks.com, then your using www.archemarks.com. Subdomains = different domains.

Comment: You can use `session_set_cookie_params()` to change the domain of the session cookie. If you set it to `.archemarks.com` it will work across all subdomains. (PS: your = you're in my first comment... ;-))